# Read battery level of wireless devices

Tags: python, hid

So, it's now a few hours that I googled it without get any explanation.
Please help me :D

So...
I have a wireless mouse, keyboard and headset.
For each one of them I can see the battery status on their own software.

So I decided to create a floating ICONS hover the desktop for this :)
Now after google it so hard, I manage to get to this code:

```
import hid

# Find the devices that supports the Battery Level feature
devices = hid.enumerate()
battery_devices = [device for device in devices if device['usage'] == 0x08 and device['usage_page'] == 0x84]

if len(battery_devices) == 0:
    print("No battery devices found.")
else:
    battery_device = battery_devices[0]

    # Open a connection to the device
    device = hid.device()
    device.open_path(battery_device['path'])

    # Send a feature report to request the battery level
    report_id = 0x01
    report = device.get_feature_report(report_id, 1024)

    # Extract the battery level from the report
    # The specific location of the battery level data within the report will depend on the device
    battery_level = report[2]

    # Print the battery level
    print(f"Battery level: {battery_level}")

    # Close the connection to the device
    device.close()
```

Which should look for any device that has battery feature and by their software all of them have it.
but still I don't find a single device.

for example my Mouse is Logitech G502, and Heatset Actris 7

I'm very new with this type of coding and hid library.
What did I miss?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is using the drivers directly. So you need to set it up correctly. Have you followed [here](https://github.com/apmorton/pyhidapi) and [here](https://github.com/libusb/hidapi#building-on-windows) for a complete installation?

Comment: I think you wrote code that successfully looks for HID UPSes, *not* random HID devices like keyboards and headsets that have a battery status. Usage page 132 (0x84) is full of things like Frequency, ApparentPower, OutletSystem, LowVoltageTransfer, and DelayBeforeReboot.

Comment: @ARK1375 if I remove the conditions "device['usage'] == 0x08 and device['usage_page'] == 0x84" I can see them, or that is not what you meant?

Comment: @hobbs what does it means "HID UPSes"? as I said i'm very new with this. Also what usage page should I look for? where can I learn about that more? because google don't give many results or good ones..

Comment: @Karim [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply). Newer ones connect to the computer using USB, and show up as USB HID devices.